# Layouts are empty on design preview of android studio

Tags: java, android

I have been working on a project and one day my layouts are appear empty in design of android studio.

I have already tried putting "Base." before "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" in file style.xml, I also tried cleaning project and invalidate caches/restart but nothing works.

I have this code in manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.d_sil.vismecassistence">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_vismec"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Login.Activity_Login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login.Activity_LoginServer"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Tasks.Activity_Tasks" />
        <activity android:name=".Tasks.Activity_Tasks_Client" />
        <activity android:name=".Tasks.Activity_Task_Corretiva" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity_Profile" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Notifications"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity_Historic" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity_Calendar" />
        <activity android:name=".Tasks.Activity_Task_Preventiva" />
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Layout rendering inside the IDE cannot happen if build is going on or build has failed.  Try making a successful build and remove any layout warnings if any.

Comment: Did you see any error message in the `Run` or `Build` panel?

Comment: I run app in my smartphone and work well but i can´t see what I doing when i am build layout

Comment: @Wesely No i dont have any error message

Comment: I found this error 
"NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.  Or: Automatically add all missing attributes"   How resolve ?

Answer (score 0):

For the error `NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts. Or: Automatically add all missing attributes`

It means you missed some width or height in some views.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" <<<< this
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <<< and this
    android:src="@drawable/logo_splashscreen"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

You can look into your layout.xml and see if every View has these 2 attributes.
Or if any of them been set to `0`?

If that's the reason. In the latest version of AndroidStudio, You might see some hints like this
[image]

You mentioned the whole View is blank, I might check the root view of that `activity.xml` or you can consider paste the `xml` here.

Comment: i had a few set to 0 e ai change to wrap_content and the error still keeps